# How can I install pydelay on my windows 64 bits?

Tags: python, package, pyinstaller

The console gives the error when trying to install the package
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pydelay (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for pydelay

I tried to install pydelay with pip install pydelay and did not work.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in pydelay's documentation [here](https://pydelay.sourceforge.net/#installation-and-requirements):
`The solver has not been tested on a windows machine`.
You could however probably install it in WSL (Windows Subsystem for Linux) or try the Cygwin solution mentioned in the docs that I have no idea what is.
I am pretty certain it will work in WSL though.